# atom is slow when using it with big map

Tags: clojure

I have an ETL using clojure, each thread could load different part of a file, and it also needs to get a key from business key. The data structure to store the business key to key mapping is a hash map like:

```
{"businessKey1" 1, 
 "businessKey2" 2,
 "businessKey3" 3, 
 "businessKey4" 4, 
 "businessKey5" 5 }
```

When ETL loading data from file, it parses each line from the file into columns, if the business key column could be found in the map, just return the key, e.g if it found businessKey1, then return 1. But if it found businessKey6, then need to call a web service to create a new key. I planned to use atom, so when each thread found a new key, use atom to modify the map. But the performance is supper bad. I tested the following code, it's very slow, and there are lots of GC activity.

```
(def a (atom {}))
(map #(swap! a (partial merge {% 1})) (range 10000))
(println a)
```

What's the best solution for this? Should I use ConcurrentHashMap in java?

Comment: What do you mean by "very slow"? Since maps are immutable data structures a lot of GC activity is understandable since the code is creating a new map on each `merge`. That said, GC might not be the source of the bottleneck since there is a single atom that's being modified and that needs to be synchronised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main source of the bad performance seems to be the use of `(partial merge {% 1})`

A more idiomatic form is the following:

```
(let [a (atom {})] 
  (doall (map #(swap! a merge {% 1}) (range 10000))) (println @a)))
```

Even faster is to used `assoc` and not to create a temporary map every time:

```
(let [a (atom {})] 
  (doall (map #(swap! a assoc % 1) (range 10000))) (println @a)))
```

If you want to iterate over a seq for the side effects, better use `doseq`:

```
(count (let [a (atom {})] (doseq [r (range 10000)] (swap! a assoc r 1))))
```

An atom is not necessary and what you want can be expressed as a reduction:

```
(count (reduce (fn [m r] (assoc m r 1)) {} (range 10000)))
```

Comment: Nice catch! The OP mentions using a number of threads in the ETL code so some kind of synchronisation is needed, either with an atom or other kind of Clojure reference type.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid using an atom here by using Clojure [`reducers`](http://clojure.org/reducers):

```
(require '[clojure.core.reducers :as r])

(defn lookup [k]
  ; do remote call, here it just returns 1  
  1)

(defn f
  ([] {})
  ([acc k] (if (get acc k)
             acc
            (assoc acc k (lookup k)))))

(r/fold merge f (vec (range 10000)))
```

`clojure.core.reducers/fold` will automatically run this in parallel and combine the results.

Comment: Using `fold` is wrong because it runs in parallel. For the same key `lookup` might be called twice and, thus, two different keys are created.

Comment: The above solution using fold is not wrong. Yes, if the collection contains the same key multiple times and fold partitions the collection in such a way that the same key appears in different partitions, then lookup will be invoked with the same key multiple times. The remote web service should already be catering for a create key call that contains a key that may already exist since it may have multiple concurrent remote clients and there is no guarantee that any client will not attempt to use an existing key. The web service's API contract should define how to deal with such a scenario.