# How to specify type when using ConcurrentHashMap in clojure

Tags: clojure

In java I need to tell `ConcurrentHashMap` which type the key or the value is, then in clojure how to do it. I could create a new `ConcurrentHashMap` without specifying the type of key or value, but I think if I could specify the type, then performance could be better. So how to specify key as `String` and value as `Int`.

Comment: Even in Java, Generics are a compile time only thing that isn't reflected in the byte code, and don't end up having much to do with performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance of `ConcurrentHashMap` should not be affected by the type parameter. In java the type parameter is only used by the compiler and erased at compilation.

Answer (score 2):

Clojure maps can hold any kind of value, there's no way to either limit the types it accepts as keys/values or hint the compiler to optimise for certain types.

There is however a way to hint the types of arguments and bindings to avoid reflection. Although if your question is related to the [atom is slow when using it with big map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27964880/atom-is-slow-when-using-it-with-big-map) problem you are having, I'm pretty sure specifying the types for the map won't make a difference since Clojure [`PersistentHashMap`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentHashMap.java#L119) uses [`Util.hasheq`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Util.java#L164) on every key to figure out its hash.